# Can't add time to the DATEOFFSET(2) in SQL Select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am in the need to convert a date time field on my database to be using the "T" and the Zulu time for an XML output. I got the part working where I convert the date time field to date and then convert it to zulu time with the "T" added to the output:

```
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(CONVERT(DATE,OEO.ScheduledShipDate) AS DATETIMEOFFSET(2)), 127) AS ScheduledEarlyPickup
```

The output for this is something like:

```
2001-02-11T00:00:00Z
2001-06-13T00:00:00Z
2001-11-21T00:00:00Z
2001-12-03T00:00:00Z
2002-02-16T00:00:00Z
2002-03-27T00:00:00Z
2002-04-05T00:00:00Z
2002-04-12T00:00:00Z
```

Now I need to change this to the effect where the hh:mm:ss displays 23:59:00 like:

```
2001-02-11T23:59:00Z
2001-06-13T23:59:00Z
2001-11-21T23:59:00Z
2001-12-03T23:59:00Z
2002-02-16T23:59:00Z
2002-03-27T23:59:00Z
2002-04-05T23:59:00Z
2002-04-12T23:59:00Z
```

I thought a simple code like below would do the job, but I am not sure why the data remains unchanged:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(CONVERT(DATE,OEO.ScheduledShipDate+'23:59:00') AS DATETIMEOFFSET(2)), 127)
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks,
RV

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. There was a simple syntax error that I was not paying attention to. If anyone requires this, the code is:

```
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(OEO.ScheduledShipDate + '23:59:00' AS DATETIMEOFFSET(2)), 127)
```